# If I change a line in a file, do SonarQube consider the whole file as new code or only the changed lines?

Tags: sonarqube

we want to analyse code coverage on new code.
Is SonarQube considering the converage on the whole file, or only the coverage in the area of the file that has changed?
Thank you
Regards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.